# Reason: 'simctl error running 'create': Invalid device type: Iphone Xs'

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

I'm trying to integrate and run sample automation test using `Appium`.

Followed all the mentioned steps to install and setup environment from
http://latestsoftwaretestingnews.com/mobiletesting/appium-ios-testing-with-node-js-step-by-step-guide/

From Appium Desktop v 1.13.0 (1.13.0.20190505.5), on start session always getting an error.
Please refer screenshot:

[image]

Appreciate your help! Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure your problem is the deviceName capability. Can you check your device name is EXACTLY iphone Xs? I think the problem may be that the P should be on caps.

Comment: Double checked, I've created a new device with name "iphone Xs"

Comment: OK. The other idea I have is that I think an .ipa file can not be installed on a simulator and you should use a .app file.

Comment: also tried with .app file but wont work

Comment: if the parameter's above are  being mapped to the xcrun simctl create command, then the device types should be one listed by the command : xcrun simctl list devicetypes

Answer (score 0):

.ipa files can not be used with simulators, you have to use a .app file instead.

Answer (score -1):

@Harshal Wani - First just try to deploy the ipa to that simulator by command line, also try launching the simulator and deploy the app via Xcode..